# Delete directories with given folder name

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to write a cron job which would run on a Raspberry Pi and that would once every few days or once every two weeks run and delete some folders, these folders are date specific, and are generated automatically, e.g:

```sh
2020-02-08
2020-02-09
2020-02-10
2020-02-11
2020-02-12
2020-02-13
2020-02-14
2020-02-15
2020-02-16
```

I'd like to be able to loop over these, and delete the past X days folders, whilst retaining the past Z days folders, e.g:

delete:

```sh
2020-02-08
2020-02-09
2020-02-10
2020-02-11
```

keep:

```sh
2020-02-12
2020-02-13
2020-02-14
2020-02-15
2020-02-16
```

and then in 4 - 5 days time it would run again, deleting the ones it kept from the previous week, and so fourth.

I know that I can run `rm -rf 2020-*` to delete all of the folders/files beginning with that, but I need a script to do the above for me!

Also, in each folder would be thousands of files, this is something to bear in mind with a good perform ant deletion process

Comment: If you have only **one** directory per day, and the name of the directories is so simple, can't you just be [a bad guy](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and parse `ls` taking the first X entries of its output?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis , why bother parsing `ls` if the names match actual timestamps?  `find -mtime +5 -type d -name 2020-\*` ...

Comment: @tink , that was my first idea, but then I thought that if the directories have those names maybe those names are not necessarily equal to the time stamps. But it seems they are indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Execute this command in the parent directory:

```
find  . -mtime +5 -type d -name 2020-\* -exec rm  -rf {} \;
```

The command above will find all directories that are greater than 5 days old and have a name that matches 2020-* ( you may want to consider making this a little more future proof and perhaps go with 2* ).   All directories with that name (and modification time) will be removed.

You may want to hold off on the -exec part of that command.  Try this command first:

```
find  . -mtime +5 -type d -name 2\*
```

This will let you know that the found directories are the one's you want to remove before you go ahead and delete them.